# Bipartite graphs that are not incidence graphs of hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hypergraphs

At [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) one reads:

> "[...] most, but not all, [bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) can be regarded as
> [incidence graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_structure#Graphs) of [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph).

I wonder which bipartite graphs can **not** be regarded as incidence graphs of hypergraphs.

The only counterexamples I can imagine are bipartite graphs in which one of the nodes representing hyperedges (node type 1) has degree less than 2 because hyperedges connect at least 2 "proper" nodes (node type 2). Proper nodes with degree less than 2 are allowed. (When loops are allowed, also hyperedge nodes with degree 1 are allowed.)

Are there other counterexamples?

Comment: Two vertices on the edge side with the same neighborhood on the vertex side would correspond to a "multi-edge" in the hypergraph. This is technically not allowed in the definition since they specify that the edges for a set. If the edges are allowed to be a multiset, then multi-edges are okay.

Comment: @dbal: Ah, I have overseen this case. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: In practice, it's much more common to consider only uniform hypergraphs, which corresponds to bipartite graphs which are regular on one side. It can help to turn a hypergraph into a bipartite graph, but it usually doesn't help to go the other way, because the hypergraph you get isn't very nice even if that does work.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: What is a "nice" hypergraph?

Comment: "Uniform" or "simple" or "not containing an edge of size $0$ or $1$". It's situational, but whatever nice properties you want your hypergraphs to have, the ones you get from a general bipartite graph probably won't.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: There may be good reasons to consider non-uniform hypergraphs. As in the case of non-preferential attachment I did not find so much about general (non-uniform) hypergraphs (no thorough treatments, only about uniform hypergraphs). Do you know a good resource?

Comment: Non-uniform hypergraphs are just set families. Those are very well studied, just not under the guise of graph theory.